# [Intellij][Maven] How to use project as dependency to another

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have two different maven projects and I'm working on Intellij .. how I can add one of them with its dependencies to the other project as dependency?

I easily can do it like this from Eclipse
[image]

So how I can do it from Intellij ?

**UPDATE**

I succeed with adding the module as dependency, but the module dependencies are not visible to the original project

**==>** Project A, Project B ,,, B has many dependencies,, I added B into A as dependency ,, A now can access all B modules but it cannot see the B dependencies

Comment: Hi, please paste your image inside of the question, no link (or if it's code, paste code)

Comment: I modified it ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can configure this in Project properties (`cmd +` ; on Mac, `Ctrl + alt + shift + s` on Windows/Linux). Just add a module as dependency. See the attached image as a reference.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Project properties]

Comment: thanks, this works for the project modules, but seems that the original project doesn't see the dependencies for the added project Error:(3, 27) java: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist

Comment: more explanation: Project A, Project B ,,, B has many dependencies,, I added B into A as dependency ,, A now can access all B modules but it cannot see the B dependencies

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. If you are using maven, then you should add the dependency in pom.xml, not this dialog. And also for better integration import the maven module into the same intellij project.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse notion of a workspace is slightly different from IntelliJ.

In your situation I would create a dummy parent project with each project physically located beneath referenced as submodules, so that Maven sees it as a single module.  This will let both Maven and IDE's to know that they are connected so you skip the "generate jar" step.

```
  dummy-parent
    +--- project A
    +--- project B (which references A)
```

Comment: No need to create a Maven parent, importing both Maven modules into one IntelliJ project is enough.

Comment: @Meo How do you import two modules in one InteliJ project?

Comment: Project settings | Modules | Import module